# How to fix webmail for plesk? When I click on webmail icon in plesk it doesn't shows mail

Tags: dns, plesk, webmail

Login into plesk, click on "Mail" button below "websites and domain" on left side in dashboard of Plesk. 
On clicking on mail-icon in plesk against each email new browser tab pop up but it shows this error:
This site can’t be reached webmail.mooshdigital.com’s server IP address could not be found.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

I have read some articles and watch videos on youtube but totally wasted time. Some videos and articles suggested this error is due to DNS settings.

But I have tried DNS setting as well but I'm not got at DNS setting.

Please guide me I have attached images for DNS settings and error I get when click on mail-icon.
[DNS setting inside plesk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIhtI.png)

[Error when I click on mail-icon, mail-icon shown in C1 in red color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUfqp.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your domain's (mooshdigital.com) DNS zone (when you refer to webmail.mooshdigital.com it leads nowhere sinse there is no records for sub-domains in your DNS zone). Here is info from Plesk: https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/customer-guide/websites-and-domains/domains-and-dns/adding-and-removing-domains.65150/

> Note: If you select the recommended option, you should connect the DNS
>   settings related and your domain name with the domain name at the
>   registrar’s side. To achieve this, enter the Plesk name server IP
>   address into the respective NS record of the registrar. The
>   instruction on how to obtain the IP is as follows: go to Websites &
>   Domains > domain name > DNS Settings, find the NS record, and then
>   find the A record corresponding to the NS record value.
>
> For example, if your NS record is
>
> example.com. NS ns.example.com,
>
> find the A record with ns.example.com, for example,
>
> ns.example.com. A 192.0.2.12
>
> The resulting value, 192.0.2.12, is the Plesk name server’s IP that
>   you need.